# Asynchronous writing to a bit array

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, bit-manipulation

**TL; DR** How to safely perfom a single bit update `A[n/8] |= (1<<n%8);` for `A` being a huge array of `char`s (i.e., setting `n`'s **bit** of `A` true) when computing in parallel using C++11's `<thread>` library?

---

I'm performing a computation that's easy to parallelize. I'm computing elements of a certain subset of the natural numbers, and I wanna find elements that are *not* in the subset. For this I create a huge array (like `A = new char[20l*1024l*1024l*1024l]`, i.e., 20GiB). A `n`'s **bit** of this array is true if `n` lies in my set.

When doing it in parallel and setting the bits true using `A[n/8] |= (1<<n%8);`, I seem to get a small loss of information, supposedly due to concurring work on the same **byte** of `A` (each thread has to first read the byte, update the single bit and write the byte back). How can I get around this? Is there a way how to do this update as an atomic operation?

The code follows. GCC version: `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609`. The machine is an 8-core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620  @ 2.40GHz, 37GB RAM. Compiler options: `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -O3`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

typedef long long myint; // long long to be sure

const myint max_A = 20ll*1024ll*1024ll; // 20 MiB for testing
//const myint max_A = 20ll*1024ll*1024ll*1024ll; // 20 GiB in the real code
const myint n_threads = 1; // Number of threads
const myint prime = 1543; // Tested prime

char *A; 
const myint max_n = 8*max_A;

inline char getA(myint n) { return A[n/8] & (1<<(n%8)); }
inline void setAtrue(myint n) { A[n/8] |= (1<<n%8); }

void run_thread(myint startpoint) {
    // Calculate all values of x^2 + 2y^2 + prime*z^2 up to max_n
    // We loop through x == startpoint (mod n_threads)
    for(myint x = startpoint; 1*x*x < max_n; x+=n_threads)
        for(myint y = 0; 1*x*x + 2*y*y < max_n; y++)
            for(myint z = 0; 1*x*x + 2*y*y + prime*z*z < max_n; z++)
                setAtrue(1*x*x + 2*y*y + prime*z*z);
}

int main() {
    myint n;

    // Only n_threads-1 threads, as we will use the master thread as well
    std::thread T[n_threads-1];

    // Initialize the array
    A = new char[max_A]();

    // Start the threads
    for(n = 0; n < n_threads-1; n++) T[n] = std::thread(run_thread, n); 
    // We use also the master thread
    run_thread(n_threads-1);
    // Synchronize
    for(n = 0; n < n_threads-1; n++) T[n].join();

    // Print and count all elements not in the set and n != 0 (mod prime)
    myint cnt = 0;
    for(n=0; n<max_n; n++) if(( !getA(n) )&&( n%1543 != 0 )) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
        cnt++;
    }   
    std::cout << "cnt = " << cnt << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When `n_threads = 1`, I get the correct value `cnt = 29289`. When `n_threads = 7`, I got `cnt = 29314` and `cnt = 29321` on two different calls, suggesting some of the bitwise operations on a single byte were concurring.

Comment: @MarekR That's easy to say and you're right. Yes, there are faster (in theory) ways how to do this. The practical fact is, they are not actually _that_ faster and they require sinificantly more memory.

Comment: Until we have working implementations of C++17 parallel algorithms, for a task as yours is much more suitable OpenMP with simple parallel loop construct.

Comment: Look into [compare and swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap). But I'm pretty sure whoever gave you this task expected you to come up with a more mathematically clever solution than brute-forcing over all inputs.

Comment: @MaxLanghof looks promising, I'll check it for sure. Thanks!

Comment: (sorry to contact you here) When you make https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458865/submitting-paper-made-on-overleaf-to-arxiv more generic, could you please add a short disclaimer to my answer that it refers to a (then) previous version of the question? It might be confusing otherwise. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: btw does "useful changes to the Overleaf interface soon" mean that errors will be easier to notice?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz not that specifically. And yes, I will do that in some way. (btw, you can reach me also directly by email at tom.hejda at company)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::atomic` provides all the facilities that you need here:

```
std::array<std::atomic<char>, max_A> A;

static_assert(sizeof(A[0]) == 1, "Shall not have memory overhead");
static_assert(std::atomic<char>::is_always_lock_free,
              "No software-level locking needed on common platforms");

inline char getA(myint n) { return A[n / 8] & (1 << (n % 8)); }
inline void setAtrue(myint n) { A[n / 8].fetch_or(1 << n % 8); }
```

The load in `getA` is atomic ([equivalent to `load()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T)), and `std::atomic` even has built-in support for `or`ing the stored value with another one ([`fetch_or`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_or)), atomically of course.

When initializing `A`, the naive way of `for (auto& a : A) a = 0;` would require synchronization after every store, which you can avoid by waiving some thread-safety. [`std::memory_order_release`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) only requires that what we write is visible to other threads (but not that other thread's writes are visible to us). And indeed, if you do

```
// Initialize the array
for (auto& a : A)
  a.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
```

you get the safety you need without any assembly-level synchronization on x86. You could do the reverse for the loads after the threads finish, but that has no added benefit on x86 (it's just a `mov` either way).

Demo on the full code: https://godbolt.org/z/nLPlv1

Comment: Looks good, thanks! However, in my real-life situation, A has 20 GiB, so I have to allocate it dynamically on the heap.

Comment: @yo' Yeah, but that's a separate problem. If you're doing manual memory management then you don't really care, but that's not modern C++. You unfortunately can't use `std::vector` (because you can't copy `std::atomic`s), but a `std::unique_ptr<std::array<...>>` will do the trick.

Comment: Goodness. I would be old-school and just define `std::array<...> *A` and use `(*A)` instead of `A` everywhere :D

Comment: @yo' I mean, your current code is leaking memory. Maybe you don't care here because the program ending "fixes" it, but that's not the standard that stackoverflow answers should have imo.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but for me, learning to work with yet another `std` feature is sort-of an overhead. There's a boundary between "correct" and "not much deal" somewhere :)

Comment: @yo' And if you don't practice using the features, one day you'll take a step too far away from "correct" without noticing and get completely wrong results - without noticing. Not saying it will happen here or any time soon, but the day will come.  :)

Comment: I haven't needed C++ for over 3 years. How long you think I'll remember these things?